# Set up debugger for Kubernetes pod in EKS cluster for go applications

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, remote-debugging, delve

I am trying to set up a debugger for my application which is running inside my Kubernetes pod in the EKS cluster .

I have one through many articles but they all talk about setting up a debugger for local env .

I am using helm charts and EKS for the Kubernetes cluster.
Please help me with this problem.

I tried Dockerfile changes to install delve but CMD and ENTRYPOINT command both are failing with

```
exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
```

My docker file looks like

**Stage 1: Compile the Golang application**

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /application
COPY . /application
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -v -x -o app --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"'
```

**Stage 2: Move only the compiled code to container**

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /application
COPY --from=builder /application/app /application
RUN apk add --no-cache delve
# let's start delve as the entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dlv", "debug", ".", "--listen=:40000", "--accept-multiclient", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2" , "exec" , "./app" ]
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue locally; probably not in a container, almost certainly not in a remote clustered environment?  That would make it much easier to debug, iterate on a fix, and write a test case.  (Consider how you might debug the issue if it was in a customer's on-premises environment and you couldn't connect to the cluster at all.)

Comment: I  am trying to reproduce the issue  by using minikube as my EKS cluster , however when I try to deploy my image in minikube , it says imagepullbackoff

Comment: I'm suggesting using `go` directly for this sort of debugging task – no Kubernetes or container layer at all.

Comment: any udpate on this ? feel free to update the status of question, if found below answer helpful. Don't hesitate to write your own answer if have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in **Go** but in the second stage you are copying the files from first stage to the second one.

Those files could be the **executable** or **source code**

In the second stage you have installed the **delve** but when you are adding the Entry point or CMD it's showing error of this

```
exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
```

it's due to the second stage is **alpine** won't have **Go** installed by default and as you have not copied **Go** binary from the first to the second stage so showing a **path** error or missing error as **dlv** might be requiring it in background.

What you can do is install it with in first stage and move to second stage

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
```

**stage 2**

```
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv /usr/bin/dlv
```